# How to convert data frame to dfm in quanteda package in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, quanteda

Suppose I have a data frame vector which looks like:

```
tweets
#text
#text 2
#text 3
```

Using the `quanteda` package, I'm trying to count the number of hashtags in the data frame.

However, using the following code, I get an error:

```
tweet_dfm <- dfm(data, remove_punct = TRUE)
tag_dfm <- dfm_select(tweet_dfm, pattern = ('#*'))
toptag <- names(topfeatures(tag_dfm, 50))
head(toptag)
```

Error (on the first line of code):

```
Error in dfm.default(data, remove_punct = TRUE) : dfm() only works on character, corpus, dfm, tokens objects.
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

You need to slice out the column of the data.frame called "tweets", using `data$tweets`.  So:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

data <- data.frame(tweets = c("#text", "#text 2", "#text 3"))

dfm(data$tweets, remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  dfm_select(pattern = ("#*")) %>%
  sum()
## [1] 3
```

(since you wanted the total of all hashtags)

Note that the `remove_punct = TRUE` is unnecessary here, although it has no effect - since fortunately **quanteda**'s built-in tokeniser recognises the difference between punctuation and the hashtag character that other tokenisers might consider to be a punctuation character.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. In the original post, could you please indicate what the 50 does in `toptag <- names(topfeatures(tag_dfm, 50))`?

Comment: It specifies the limit of the top features as 50.